# No gulpfile found на Ubuntu 16, когда устанавливал sass

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Установил `gulp` командой

```
npm install gulp
```

Получил

```
+ gulp@3.9.1
```

Стал устанавливать `sass`

```
gulp sass
```

Получил

```
No gulpfile found
```

В [другом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337547/local-gulp-not-found-after-installing-globally-and-locally) прочитал, что это происходит из-за того, что gulp ищет файл не там.
Что надо набрать в консоли, чтобы установить `sass` и решить проблему с `gulpfile`?

**UPD:**

```
npm install gulp-sass
gulp sass
```

тоже не помогло.

Comment: npm install gulp-sass, gulp sass - вы пытаетесь вызвать таск sass из gulpfile.js, которого видимо у вас нет.

Comment: Сделал npm install gulp-sass, gulp sass. Результат не изменился.

Comment: объясняю еще раз, gulp sass - это не установка, это вызов таска sass из файла gulpfile.js, он дает такой ответ потому что вы не создали этот файл, а установка это npm install gulp-sass. Разберитесь с тем что такое таски. На офф сайте есть вся необходимая документация.

Comment: вы меня не поняли, именно так  я и сделал.

Comment: вопрос решен. файл был в другой папке.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp нужно установить глобально:

```
npm install -g gulp
```